# Stop KDE from unmaximizing the window on dragging movement starting close to the window border

Tags: kde, window-management

I installed Fedora 21 KDE spin recently (KDE 4.14.4). It comes with some nifty window effects, for example a way to tile windows when dragging them close to an edge or a corner of a screen.

But today, I had to realize that it has an effect which makes Inkscape unusable. To create a guide, I have to click on one of the rulers around the screen and make a dragging motion onto the drawing surface. This appears to be handled by the window manager instead, and I get an unmaximized window with some kind of unusable guide in the middle of it, which cannot be dragged around as a normal guide. This did not use to be the case on older versions of operating systems with KDE (Debian and Fedora).

The effect is not restricted to Inkscape, other windows get small too when a similar drag is performed.

How do I turn off this function of "unmaximizing on inside drag", while keeping the "window tiling on outside drag" feature?

Answer (score 0):

Zombie thread, I found this question before I found the answer though, so here goes:

There are a few bug reports with patches for oxygen, but the quick fix for your average user is as follows:

> you can specify that oxygen only allows window moving via title-bar
>   drag by running "oxygen-settings" and changing the "Windows' drag
>   mode" in the "General" tab of the "Widget Style" settings. Hope that
>   helps!

https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1109812/comments/11